# Creating nested ArrayLists with nested for loops for my Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to create player orders for my darts app, but I can't make it work.

Following variables exist:

```java
int setsAmount;
int legsAmount;
int playerAmount = getMatchParticipants().size();
```

setsAmount and legsAmount variables are initialized by user input in editTexts.
setsAmount is the amount of sets a player needs to win the match. legsAmount is the amount of legs a player needs to win a set.

Let's assume the following:

```java
setsAmount = 3;
legsAmount = 3;
playerAmount = 2;
```

I want to generate player orders for each possible set and leg. Therefore I need to define more variables.
I need to calculate the amount of legs and sets that can be played at most because I want to generate the player order represented by
integer indexes for each set and leg.

The extra variables are the following:

```java
maximumSetsAmountPerMatch = playerAmount * (setsAmount - 1) + 1; // in our case = 5
maximumLegsPerSet = playerAmount * (legsAmount - 1) + 1; // in our case = 5
```

Using all these variables, I want to create ArrayLists that contains the player order for each set/leg.
ArrayList rootContainer should contain five setContainer ArrayLists (one per maximumSetsAmountPerMatch). Each of those setContainer ArrayLists should contain another five legContainer ArrayLists (one per maximumLegsPerSet).
Each of those legContainer ArrayLists should contain two Integer values (one per player).

The end result should look like that:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> rootContainer = {ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set1Container, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set2Container, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set3Container, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set4Container, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set5Container};

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set1Container = {ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg1Container, ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg2Container, ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg3Container, ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg4Container, ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg5Container};
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set2Container = {ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg1Container, ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg2Container, ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg3Container, ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg4Container, ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg5Container};
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set3Container = {ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg1Container, ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg2Container, ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg3Container, ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg4Container, ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg5Container};
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set4Container = {ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg1Container, ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg2Container, ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg3Container, ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg4Container, ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg5Container};
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set5Container = {ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg1Container, ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg2Container, ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg3Container, ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg4Container, ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg5Container};

ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg1Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg2Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg3Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg4Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set1Leg5Container = {0, 1};
ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg1Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg2Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg3Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg4Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set2Leg5Container = {1, 0};
ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg1Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg2Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg3Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg4Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set3Leg5Container = {0, 1};
ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg1Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg2Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg3Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg4Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set4Leg5Container = {1, 0};
ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg1Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg2Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg3Container = {0, 1}; ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg4Container = {1, 0}; ArrayList<Integer> set5Leg5Container = {0, 1};
```

So basically, the integer values in the leg containers should shift one position to the right for each leg. And the indexes of the first leg containers also always shift one element to the right in comparison to the last first leg container as seen above.

How do I automate that process? Probably with nested for loops, but I was not able to get it done. Or is there an easier process to achieve what I want?
I hope I explained it good enough so everyone understands what I exactly mean.

Comment: It is some hard to understand your problem. This problem seems a huge one that needs to be broken down into smaller chunks of problem. It'd be better if you would have added the class or classes that you implement for this in the manner of minimal reproducible example. If your problem is only on how to create that nested list using a for loop, then what are the criterias to drive the for loops?

Comment: It is indeed a little bit hard to understand. Since I wasn't able to make it work the way I wanted to I now solved it differently. Instead of creating all arraylists at the beginning of the match I now create only one after each leg/set that shifts its elements in relation to the previous one.